# Shifting Arrows Down in Chemformula

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, chemformula

I would like to shift the arrow and the CO down so that it is more to the middle of the structure on the left. I am not sure how to shift arrows in the `chemformula` package.

My code so far:

```
 \documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
  \usepackage{chemfig}
   \usepackage{chemformula}
        \begin{document}

    \chemfig{[:-30]@{g}N-@{a}Fe([:-150]-@{b}N)([:30]-@{c}N)([:-30]-@{d}N)
    ([:90,1.2]-@{e}O_2)([:-90,1.2,,1]-@{f}HISTIDINE) ([:-120,0.83,,,white]-@{z})  
    } \ch{ + CO -> }
    \chemfig{[:-30]@{q}N-@{r}Fe([:-150]-@{s}N)([:30]-@{t}N)([:-30]-@{u}N)
    ([:90,1.2]-@{v}CO)([:-90,1.2,,1]-@{w}HISTIDINE) ([:-120,0.83,,,white]-@{h}) 
    } \ch{ + O2}

    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (d) to[bend left] node {} (b);}
    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (g) to[bend right] node {}(b);}
    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (g) to[bend left] node {}(c);}
    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (c) to[bend left] node {}(d);} 
    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (z) to[bend right] node {}(f);} 

    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (u) to[bend left] node {} (s);}
    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (q) to[bend right] node {}(s);}
    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (q) to[bend left] node {}(t);}
    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (t) to[bend left] node {}(u);} 
    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (h) to[bend right] node {}(w);} 
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The solution to alignment for this circumstance is given on p64 of V1.2d of the `ChemFig` manual. The method relies on "stopping" the drawing of each molecule once it has been completed. This is achieved by adding an invisible arrow using `\arrow{0}[,0]` after each molecule is drawn.

The summary of the changes are:

1. Add `\arrow{0}[,0]` after each molecule
2. Wrapped the reaction in `\schemestart` `\schemestop`
3. Use the `\+` macro (see p23)
4. Use the `\arrow` macro (see p47)
5. I added `\schemedebug{true}` to show bounding boxes and anchors

This is the full code:

```
 \documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
  \usepackage{chemfig}
   \usepackage{chemformula}
        \begin{document}
            \schemedebug{true}
    \schemestart[][east]
    \chemfig{[:-30]@{g}N-@{a}Fe([:-150]-@{b}N)([:30]-@{c}N)([:-30]-@{d}N)
    ([:90,1.2]-@{e}O_2)([:-90,1.2,,1]-@{f}HISTIDINE) ([:-120,0.83,,,white]-@{z})  
    } 
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+ \ch{CO}
    \arrow
    \chemfig{[:-30]@{q}N-@{r}Fe([:-150]-@{s}N)([:30]-@{t}N)([:-30]-@{u}N)
    ([:90,1.2]-@{v}CO)([:-90,1.2,,1]-@{w}HISTIDINE) ([:-120,0.83,,,white]-@{h}) 
    }
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+
    \ch{O2}
    \schemestop

    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (d) to[bend left] node {} (b);}
    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (g) to[bend right] node {}(b);}
    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (g) to[bend left] node {}(c);}
    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (c) to[bend left] node {}(d);} 
    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (z) to[bend right] node {}(f);} 

    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (u) to[bend left] node {} (s);}
    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (q) to[bend right] node {}(s);}
    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (q) to[bend left] node {}(t);}
    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (t) to[bend left] node {}(u);} 
    \chemmove {\draw [clip] (h) to[bend right] node {}(w);} 
 \end{document}
```

[image]